# Can I view previous passwords?

Tags: ios, password

Im on ios. I did the wrong thing changing my scratch account password and my iphone saved the wrong one. I can’t reset it since i dont have my old password (randomly generated secure one). Im stuck on my phone. I shared a project about it and ive had that account for over 4 years and have tons of followers and stuff

Comment: There's no history, it would be unsafe. You will need to contact 'scratch' & go through their 'forgot password' structure.

Comment: How would it be unsafe. 1password does keep old passwords

Answer (score 1):

There’s no history of passwords.

If you use iCloud Keychain and have another device on the same iCloud account, there’s a chance it hasn’t synchronised yet. Turn off the internet so it doesn’t perform a sync, then check your password there.

If not, follow the password reset functionality of the website.